# how to increase or decrease the count based on array index

Tags: javascript, react-native

I need increase or decrease the product count based on the array index. while using this function data value is updating but flatlist not get rendering the updated value

```
import  React ,{useState} from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet,FlatList,Button } from 'react-native';

const addCount = () => {
  const [data,setData] = useState([{
    id : 1,
  name : "Mongo",
  price : 30,
  qty : 1
},
{
  id : 2,
  name : "lemon",
  price : 30,
  qty : 1
}])
const addQty = (ind) => {
setData(data[ind].qty + 1)
}
  return (
    <View>
  <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem= {({item,index})=>{
          return (
            <View>
            <Text>name: {item.name}</Text>
            <Text>qty : {item.qty}</Text>
            <Text>price : {item.price}</Text>
            <Button  title = "add Qty" onPress = {()=>{
              addQty(index)
            }}/>
            </View>
          )
        }}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
    </View>
  )
}

export default addCount
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not directly **mutate** the array instead you have to provide a new array
in order to update the state so try:

```
setData(data.map((obj,index)=> index == ind ? { ...obj, qty:obj.qty+1} : obj ))
```

Comment: spread operator is not updating qty instead adding the new index to existing array

Comment: sry, I have uptaded the aswer, now it is working

Comment: And make sure to name  every react component in PascalCase (in this case AddCount)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228428/discussion-between-shreyas-hc-and-jenish-jerald).

Answer (score 0):

Just update the code as below, and make it so simple, as we are iterating over the json object, we don't want to use the spread operator,

`setData(data.map((obj, index) => index == ind ? obj.qty++ : obj))`